# Creating a non-standard time-based trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello to everyone and thanks for the help.

I have two different scripts, and each one needs to run automatically every 14 days at a specific hour of the day. (Yes, it's payroll-related.) I haven't seen a trigger that will do this, but then again, I may have missed something...

Anybody care to weigh in about how this can be done?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyHours(Integer) Not sure if this will actually work or not!

Comment: This is in a separate script/project (Tools>Script Editor)

function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {

// Trigger every Thursday at 09:00.

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("End_Of_WK1")
      .timeBased()
      .everyWeeks(2)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY)
      .atHour(9)
      .create();
}

IDK if this will work. Anybody have any experience with actually using this or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to programmatically set up triggers and initialize it the first time. Create a new date with

```
var runTime = new Date()
```

and you can then simply offset the date with

```
runTime.setDate(runTime.getDate() + 14)
```

and set the exact runtime, for example

```
runTime.setHours(12)
runTime.setMinutes(0)
```

to run at 12:00 (no point in going deeper, because it will be with a 15 minute error margin as it can run as late as 12:15). Read [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atdate) on how to set up the trigger.

This will simply have to be done every time you run the script. You clear the old trigger and have the function create a new one for next time. Since you work with a date object, you can also highly customize this to run for example every 10th of the month, or every second Thursday etc. Really depends on how well you know how to manipulate the date objects.

Comment: Vytautas, a question: When you say "This will simply have to be done every time you run the script. You clear the old trigger and have the function create a new one for next time." Can't this be done programmatically? (And if so, how?) Once the 2-week trigger is tested and working properly, I want to change the trigger time to every other Friday at 1:00 AM.

Comment: @user3279926 For example your trigger starts a function called `runThis()`. What I mean is that the last thing (or the first thing, it's up to you) `runThis()` has to do is delete the trigger. To do this have `runThis(trigger)` which will give you `trigger.triggerUid` you can use to delete the right one. After that is done, the function will have to create a new trigger for the correct time. That way it will be a loop of triggers. Old one gets deleted (to keep things clean), new one gets created.